# How to get one of the specific values(with the specific index) of this iterable enumerate (results.pose_landmarks.landmark)?

Tags: python, python-3.x, opencv, pose-estimation, mediapipe

```py
import cv2 #OpenCV is the library that we will be using for image processing
import mediapipe as mp #Mediapipe is the framework that will allow us to get our pose estimation
import time


mpDraw = mp.solutions.drawing_utils
mpPose = mp.solutions.pose

pose = mpPose.Pose()
#pose = mpPose.Pose(static_image_mode = False, upper_body_only = True) #ONLY UPPER_BODY_TRACKING

#cap = cv2.VideoCapture(0)
cap = cv2.VideoCapture('PoseVideos/1_girl_choreography.mp4')

pTime = 0 #previous time

while True:
    success, img = cap.read() #that will give it our image and then we can write the cv2.imshow()
    imgRGB = cv2.cvtColor(img, cv2.COLOR_BGR2RGB) #convert our image to RGB because Mediapipe use that format
    results = pose.process(imgRGB) #we are simply going to send this image to our model

    #print(enumerate(results.pose_landmarks.landmark)) #<enumerate object at 0x0000012312DD1A00>

    #so then we will check if it is detected or not
    if results.pose_landmarks:

        mpDraw.draw_landmarks(img, results.pose_landmarks, mpPose.POSE_CONNECTIONS) 

        for id, lm in enumerate(results.pose_landmarks.landmark):

            h, w, c = img.shape #get dimensions(h height, w width) and the c channel of image
            
            print(id)
            print(lm)

            cx, cy = int(lm.x * w), int(lm.y * h)

            cv2.circle(img, (cx, cy), 5, (255, 0, 0), cv2.FILLED)


    cTime = time.time()
    fps = 1 / (cTime - pTime)
    pTime = cTime

    cv2.putText(img, str(int(fps)), (70, 50), cv2.FONT_HERSHEY_PLAIN, 3, (255, 0, 0), 3)

    cv2.imshow("Image", img)
    cv2.waitKey(1)
```

I want to do what the for does but instead of doing it for all the elements (id) inside the enumerate (), do it only for the id = 25, because in this case it is the only point that interests me.

What would I need to change in this instruction of the loop that uses as iterable to this `enumerate(results.pose_landmarks.landmark):`

How would I enter an `id[25]` and a `lm[25]` ?

I try with itertools, but ir does work in this case

```py
import itertools

gen = (id, lm for id, lm in enumerate(results.pose_landmarks.landmark))
specific_id, specific_lm = 25,25 #index
print( next(itertools.islice(gen, specific_id, None)) )
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can directly access results.pose_landmarks.landmark, no need to enumerate.

```
lm = results.pose_landmarks.landmark[25]
```

results.pose_landmarks.landmark is a list

Answer (score 1):

You could try:

```
for id, lm in enumerate(results.pose_landmarks.landmark):
    if not id == 25:
        continue
    ...
```

Not elegant, but gets the job done.

Comment: I tried what it says in that thread that you put, but it keeps failing. I do not consider it to be a duplicate question. There I updated my question, but it still doesn't work for me.